# How to expand treeview for specific node on page load

Tags: jquery, treeview, load, expand

I have a treeview that expands correctly manually. But I need it to partially expand on page load. Which part expands will be determined by the ID in the url. In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/u26gpv79/6/) I have added id="xyz" to one of the nested sections to simulate this action. So when the page loads, the entire part of the tree above and including that element should expand, but it doesn't. Would someone please take a look?

```
    <style>
    ul, #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    #myUL {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .box {
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
      -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
      -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
      user-select: none;
    }

    .box::before {
      content: "\2610";
      color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 6px;
    }

    .check-box::before {
      content: "\2611"; 
      color: dodgerblue;
    }

    .nested {
      display: none;
    }

    .active {
      display: block;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <li><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li>Black Tea</li>
            <li>White Tea</li>
            <li><span class="caret" id="xyz">Green Tea</span>
              <ul class="nested">
                <li>Sencha</li>
                <li>Gyokuro</li>
                <li>Matcha</li>
                <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="caret">Food</span>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li>Black Tea</li>
            <li>White Tea</li>
            <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
              <ul class="nested">
                <li>Sencha</li>
                <li>Gyokuro</li>
                <li>Matcha</li>
                <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </li>

    <script>
     let $carets = $('.caret').on('click', e => {
        let $caret = $(e.target);
        
        // display the clicked item
        $caret.toggleClass('caret-down');
        $caret.closest('li').children('.nested').toggleClass('active');
        
      });
      
      $("#xyz").addClass('caret-down');
      let $parentCarets = $("#xyx").parents('li').children('.caret'); 
      $("#xyx").not($parentCarets).addClass('caret-down').closest('li').find('.nested').addClass('active');
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the closest `li` near `span` tag using `.closest()` then use `.find()` to get all `ul` but not the one after the span tag and then add some class to other `uls` i.e : `unselect` just to help in hiding that ul .

Then , you can get outer `li` tag and use `:not` to select all `ul` which don't have the `unselect` class and add `active` class to those `uls` only .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let $carets = $('.caret').on('click', e => {
  let $caret = $(e.target);

  // display the clicked item
  $caret.toggleClass('caret-down');
  $caret.closest('li').children('.nested').toggleClass('active');

});

$("#xyz").addClass('caret-down bg');
//get closest li -> not first ul add some class to other
$("#xyz").closest('li').find('ul.nested:not(:first)').addClass("unselect")
//get closest li-> find ul ->show that
$("#xyz").closest('li.outer').find("ul:not(.unselect)").toggleClass('active');
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <!-- added this outer class -->
  <li class="outer"><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret" id="xyz">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="outer"><span class="caret">Food</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is much closer but there are two issues. Here's my updated jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/u26gpv79/26/ I added an ID setting and a node after the last nested (named single). Your code is finding that node but it is opening the nested node before it. Is there a way to not do that? Also, I use unicode for fontawesome. It doesn't show in the demo but I didn't mention it since it didn't matter. But with this last change, the icon is being added to the selected item when it shouldn't be. I don't know how to show that in the jsfiddle but it happens here locally.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/vbg5wqdt/1/) fiddle solved first issue .. i am not sure about second issue without seeing code ..

Comment: Thank you for sticking with this. I have changed the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/u26gpv79/39/ - to show the two problems. You can see the +/- icons now. When a node is opened, the icon should be - but it stays at +. And I added the "Last Group" section and changed the ID to one of those. If the ID is on a single node, as previously, your code works. But when it is on a node in a ul, the ul's above it open. I hope this makes it easier to see the problems.

Comment: Hi, here is [update](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/37tsh98e/4/) code. Let me know if you didn't understood something also i have made few changes in html as well..you will come to know why.. please go through code..hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that brought back a previous problem. In this version - https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/u26gpv79/41/ - I copied your latest code and then changed the id = 70 to id = 50. That selects the "single" node. When it is ran, the nested group above it expands but it shouldn't since it had not been clicked on. In my code here, where there are many nested nodes, they all open when a node farther down the list is clicked.

Comment: This is making me mad now :P not sure if i could solve this .. you can ask another question ..maybe someone  else might provide better solution..:)

Comment: I understand completely. I truly appreciate you sticking with it as long as you did. I'll let it sit for a while and try again at some later date since I'm frustrated too. :)